# How do I remove Xubuntu title bar text shadow in WM Dark themes?

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce, 21.04

For most applications, but not all, title bars if in dark theme, has text shadow. Badly rendered apps include Thunar and XFCE terminal.

I am happy to install a compatible theme, but no themes in https://www.xfce-look.org/ seems to fix the problem.

[image: titlebar rendering]

```
> neofetch --off
polv@polv-ubuntu 
---------------- 
OS: Xubuntu 21.04 x86_64 
Host: 81D2 Lenovo ideapad 330-15ARR 
Kernel: 5.11.0-18-generic 
Uptime: 1 hour, 4 mins 
Packages: 2183 (dpkg), 6 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.4 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: Xfce 4.16 
WM: Xfwm4 
WM Theme: Greybird 
Theme: Greybird-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: elementary-xfce-darker [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
Terminal Font: Monospace 12 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (8) @ 2.200GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series 
Memory: 2055MiB / 11580MiB
```

Comment: There is no question still in your description (though the *rant* is now gone).  Not all browser/setups allow the title to be seen when the page is opened (not everyone is using PCs with large screens etc) so details in the title need to also be inside your question.  You've now provided the release details (ie. 21.04 & a fully GTK3 system).

Comment: @guiverc I inclded the whole `neofetch --off`.

Comment: Try a different GTK theme, (e.g. the Arc theme or Mint-Y theme) that does not have such a text shadow.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Arc-Dark doesn't appear to fix it. I don't know how to install Mint-Y in Ubuntu.

Comment: Mint-Y and Mint-X http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mint-themes/mint-themes_1.8.8_all.deb

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mint-themes : Depends: mint-x-icons but it is not installable
               Depends: mint-y-icons but it is not installable`

Comment: Oh ok. Mint X icons : http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mint-x-icons/mint-x-icons_1.6.3_all.deb  Mint Y icons : http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mint-y-icons/mint-y-icons_1.5.8_all.deb   I found them here: http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Uma

Comment: I don't have Xubuntu installed right now, but here's how Mint-Y-Dark looks on XFCE. https://imgur.com/lnVFrlG.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126651/discussion-between-polv-and-archisman-panigrahi).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `appearance` settings do not change the theme of the titlebars of non-CSD apps.

To change the theme of the titlebars of software with a server side decoration, open `Window Manager` from the menu and change the theme there.

[image]